# Using include statements, and ?view - ?view is redirecting to the wrong include

Tags: php, sql, view, include

I'm having a few problems with the following.

Essentially I'm building a login system using php/sql.

The root folder (www) contains the css styles, the index.php and some other php files which are unrelated.

Also in this folder is a folder called views. In "views" there are 2 more folders: main and layout.

Layout folder contains a a nubmer of php files that simply have 1 line in them. e.g

```
<h1> You have logged in! </h1>
```

(loginconfirm.php), or

```
<h1> Log in failed </h1>
```

(loginfailed.php).

Main folder contains 2 php files, "layout" and "loggedinlayout".

In my index file, at the end - I have this:

```
include 'views/main/'.$controller.'.php';
```

The idea, is that when the user has logged in, i change $controller from = layout, to = loggedinlayout. This would result in the new layout being loaded.

In reality this does not work as I can'get the include line to work, and it will just keep on using what it has been using before.

```
    <?php
    // occasional bugs bring up notices, this ignores them
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    // includes the database and cart functions
    include('db_function.php');
    session_start();

   // defaults to index view unless a different view is requested
   $view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'welcome' : $_GET['view'];



   function validateUser()
   {
   session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
   $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
   $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
   }

   function isLoggedIn()
   {
   if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
    return true;
   return false;
   }

   function logout()
   {
     $_SESSION = array(); //destroy all of the session variables
      session_destroy();
   }

   switch($view) {
   case "logout";
logout();
$controller='layout';
//$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
header('Location:index.php');
break;

    case "login";
    $user = ($_POST['username']); 
    $pw = ($_POST['password']); 

    session_start(); //must call session_start before using any $_SESSION variables
    //connect to the database here
    db_connect();
    $qry = "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pw'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such user exists
    {
    header('Location: ?view=loginfailed');
    die();
    }
    else
    {
    validateUser(); //sets the session data for this user
    }
    //redirect to another page or display "login success" message
     header('Location: ?view=loginconfirm');
     break;
     }

    //used for layout
    // the layout folder is where we put all the different views php files,
    // such as the index (first page displayed, even though there is another index)
    // or view players for example
     if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid']) 
     {
    $controller = 'loggedinlayout';
     }
     $controller = 'layout';

     // KEEP THIS HERE ALWAYS - THIS IS OUT OF THE CASE/VIEW SECTION

    include 'views/main/'.$controller.'.php';


     ?>
```

Have you guys got any suggestions?

The problem is - when I login, it shoudld redirect me to the login confirm page, using "loggedinlayout" as the layout, rather than "layout"

Comment: if you can't be bothered to format your code, why should anyone else be bothered to wrap their head around your mess?  btw you have an unconditional `$controller = 'layout' just before the `include` statement.  might be related to your problem.

Comment: My apologies, a few errors with my formatting there, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$controller` `if/else` statement is missing the `else`, so it will always set it to `$controller = 'layout';` even if `(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])` returns `TRUE`. Try changing this -

```
if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid']) 
 {
$controller = 'loggedinlayout';
 }
 $controller = 'layout';
```

to this -

```
if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid']) 
 {
$controller = 'loggedinlayout';
 }
else
 {
 $controller = 'layout';
 }
```